# How to wrap multi-line comments in another comment in CSS?

Tags: css, comments

In css, I can do comments like this

```
/* test */
p {
    color: red;
}
/* test2 */
h1 {
    color: red;
}
/* test3 */
h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

but now what if I wanted to comment test2 and test3. This doesn't work.

```
/* test */
p {
    color: red;
}
/*
    /* test2 */
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
    /* test3 */
    h2 {
        color: red;
    }
*/
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* test3 */
```

should be only

```
/* test3
```

to keep it open until the last `*/`

Comment: But then if I didn't do the outer comment wrapping, the opening comment of test3 makes the rest of the css commented. I'm looking to nest comments.

Comment: If you wanna comment that test3/h2 block it should be like this:
/* test */
p {
    color: red;
}
/*
/* test2 */
h1 {
    color: red;
}
/* test3
h2 {
    color: red;
}
*/

Answer (score 0):

To comment multiple lines in CSS, just don't close your

```
/*
```

You can have something like that :

```
/* test 
p {
color: red;
}
 test2
h1 {
color: red;
}
*/

/* test3 */
h2 {
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just coment all what u dont need

```css
/*
line1
Line2
line3
 */
 Line 4
line5
/*again*/
```

Comment: Thats not what I am asking. I am asking how to nest comments in other comments.

Comment: /* test */
p {
    color: red;
}
/*------------comment start
/* test2 */---- comment end
h1 {
    color: red;
}
/* test3 */
h2 {
    color: red;
}
*/ thats why not working u must remove end comments